# Issue with camera Unity augmented reality and CardIO

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, avfoundation, cardio

I have a project with unity augmented reality integreated, and also I'm using CardIO SDK. Problem comes when trying to scan a card, the CardIO screen appears but when the camera is about to open it crashes. My guess is that since I have unity running when the app is started, the camera is already opened but not shown (unity view is not shown in the main window), so I'm thinking that turning off the camera that unity is using will solve this issue. How can I turn off and turn on camera manually? 
Has someone faced this issue? Please help!